# R dataframe combine columns in dataframe based on other columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(~home, ~visitor, ~hcountry, ~vcountry,
"Milan", "Manchester", "ITA", "ENG",
"LIVERPOOL", "MILAN", "ENG", "ITA",
"Real Madrid", "Juventus", "SPA", "ITA")

#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   home        visitor    hcountry vcountry
#>   <chr>       <chr>      <chr>    <chr>   
#> 1 Milan       Manchester ITA      ENG     
#> 2 LIVERPOOL   MILAN      ENG      ITA     
#> 3 Real Madrid Juventus   SPA      ITA
```

and would like to get only the italian teams ie: Milan, Milan, Juventus...how is it possible without using loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I recommend a basic R tutorial to familiarise yourself with basic R data operations like subsetting etc. See for example [R for Beginners](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Paradis-rdebuts_en.pdf) on CRAN.

In your case you can do:

```
df[df$hcountry == "ITA" | df$vcountry == "ITA", ]
#    home    visitor hcountry vcountry
#1       Milan Manchester      ITA      ENG
#2   LIVERPOOL      MILAN      ENG      ITA
#3 Real Madrid   Juventus      SPA      ITA
```

Or

```
subset(df, hcountry == "ITA" | vcountry == "ITA")
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "home  visitor  hcountry vcountry
Milan Manchester ITA ENG
LIVERPOOL MILAN ENG ITA
'Real Madrid' Juventus SPA ITA", header  =T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could try stacking home and visitor countries to find unique values

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% gather(key1, country, -c(home, visitor)) %>% 
  gather(key2, team, -c(key1, country)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(key1, key2), substr, start=1, stop=1) %>% 
  filter(key1==key2) %>% select(-key1, -key2) %>% 
  mutate(team=tools::toTitleCase(tolower(team))) %>% 
  filter(country=="ITA") %>% 
  distinct()

#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   country team    
#>   <chr>   <chr>   
#> 1 ITA     Milan   
#> 2 ITA     Juventus
```

Remove last `distinct()` if you want to see Milan value duplicated

Answer (score 0):

We can use `filter` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    filter(hcountry == "ITA" | vcountry == "ITA")
```